# Grabbing environment variables configured in a jar file using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-boot, environment-variables

I'm working on a web application that uses spring boot, JavaScript and REST API to interact with the database. I have a jar file where I configured several environment variables that store urls and parts of urls. In Spring Boot controller I used the following line to grab an environment variable:

```
@Resource 
private Environment environment;
String prefix = environment.getProperty("rest.resource.name");
```

Is there something equivalent I could use with JavaScript to perform this operation?

Comment: No, client side JS can't interact with the underlying system. You need to ask the server to send it to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that directly, however, you could use a templating language (Thymeleaf, Velocity or even JSPs) and put a `<script>` block inside your template.

An example with Thymeleaf:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
  /*<![CDATA[*/
    var myProperty = /*[[${@environment.getProperty('rest.resource.name')}]]*/ null;   
</script>
```

Now you can use `myProperty` inside your JavaScript code (at least if you put your JavaScript sources below this script block in your HTML page).

With JSP you can do a similar thing:

```
<spring:eval expression="@environment.getProperty('rest.resource.name')" var="myProperty"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myProperty = '${myProperty}';
</script>
```